# Compile error while compiling libyaml under windows 7

Tags: yaml, compilation

I am trying to compile libyaml under Windows 7 with MingW.

I have tried to compile 0.1.2 and 0.1.3 but I get this error:

```
api.c:579: error: failure in redeclaration of 'yaml_token_delete': dllimport'd symbol lacks external linkage.
api.c:579: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

Have anyone else seen this error? Do you guys and gals know how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a patch floating around the ruby installer community that I'm hoping points to a fix [here](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/resources/patches/yaml/0001-Proper-mingw-YAML_DECLARE-definition.patch).  I had to manually patch the yaml-0.1.3 include/yaml.h file, changing the line:

```
...
#ifdef WIN32
...
```

to

```
...
#if defined(__MINGW32__)
#   define  YAML_DECLARE(type)  type
#elif defined(WIN32)
...
```

I'm still compiling, but I'm hopeful.  Hopefully this will help you also.

Comment: Tried to compile standalone libyaml without rubyinstaller runner and it worked! Will try the whole shebang later! thanks!