# Compiling libyaml on Windows

Tags: windows, mingw, yaml

So, I was developing an awesome project running Linux and I need to make the port on Windows. Problem is, the libyaml is part of my dependencies, and I need to compile it for Windows.

So I got my cygwin environment running, I ran ./configure and make, and everything went well : the library was built, I got the .a file.

Except that the makefile never ended because it couldn't build the examples : turns out some symbols are missing from the library :

```
undefined reference to `_imp__yaml_parser_initialize'
undefined reference to `_imp__yaml_parser_set_input_file'
undefined reference to `_imp__yaml_parser_scan'
undefined reference to `_imp__yaml_token_delete'
undefined reference to `_imp__yaml_parser_delete'
```

So of course, wondering how could this possibly be true, I went on searching said symbols, and I, in fact, found them in the binary, although the symbol is a tiny bit different as you can see :

```
$ nm src/.libs/libyaml.a | grep parser_set_input_file
000005a8 T _yaml_parser_set_input_file
```

So, this is usually how function name are presented when I compile a dinamicaly loadable library. What buzzes me is, WHY can't the linker find these functions ? Where does this *imp* come from ?

And what can I do so that my programs can link properly to the libyaml ? Everything else is working just as it should except for these functions.

Will you be the one to save me from this devilish compilo-linking stuff ?
I thank thee for your attention.

EDIT: I've been working on this problem for a few more hours now.
So, apparently it *MAY* come from mingw : the gcc from cygwin doesn't have any issue in compiling the examples.
However the errors remain, even if I try to do so with the cygwin's gcc. I'm starting to get sick of this retarded OS. Everytime I'm developing on Windows I spend more time solving problems than actually working. Why does it always have to be such a pain ??

Isn't there an EASY way to explain the linker not to search for mangled name of those functions ?

EDIT: I found this :
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-04/msg00942.html
Seems like a similar problem someone was having with ncurses. Though I haven't been able to make anything out of this.

Comment: -1: less than 2 minutes of searching with Google found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3273486/467957), with an answer that refers to a patch. I tried the patch and the build now runs to completion.

Comment: Yeah I found this as well. I don't have any problem compiling the library. I have problems LINKING it. Also YOU'RE the one not doing your homework, this patch has been added in 0.1.4 of libyaml, so this comment is totally irrelevant. Thanks for the -1, really what I needed after hours working on this.

Comment: You say make stops with an error when it's trying to build the test programs. I downloaded and tried to build the library and received the same exact errors. After applying the patch make finishes succesfully. Looking at `include/yaml.h` in the sources for libyaml 0.1.4 I downloaded I don't see evidence of this patch having been applied.

Comment: Oh. Indeed. It's not in the original header. Anyway the patch was applied and I still have the very same problem than after my edit : examples compiles. My project doesn't. And the project has the error the examples used to have (mangled names).

Comment: That's odd. Are you sure the patched `yaml.h` installed correctly and your project is not including some old version that's lying around somewhere? The `_imp_` prefix of the symbols gets added because the functions have been declared with the `dllimport` attribute, which is just what the patch should be helping to avoid.

Comment: Well, I just finished rebuilding the whole thing from scratch. I don't know why but there's a difference : the lib produced now takes 200 instead of 400kb. Still it produces the same error as before when I try to compile my project (and I did double-checked that I was indeed compiling with the right file).

Comment: Have you tried adding `-DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC` to your compile flags?

Comment: Just tried it :/ ! Same result ! This time I also fully reinstalled cygwin and mingw. Just to be sure.

Comment: Holy crap... I feel filthy but I worked around it. Fortunatly just a few file used the libyaml : so I made my own build of the libyaml, except this one includes my files. And it friggin' works ! Only problem now is how I'm going to concile it with the Unix version, which is still going to use the regular libyaml... a real solution would still be welcome but I kinda feel like it's a lost cause.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but the answer is still unclear. The following works for version 0.1.5:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC" --enable-static --disable-shared
```